# Laravel relationship returning name instead of id

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables. The user permission table indicates which user has which permission.

**User table**

```
id | name
 1 | jack
 2 | bob
```

**Permission table**

```
id |     name
 1 |  manage users
 2 |  manage jobs
```

**User Permission table**

```
id | user_id | permission_id
 1 |    1    |     1
 2 |    1    |     2
 3 |    2    |     1
```

**User model**

```
public function userPermission()
{
   return $this->hasMany(UserPermission::class);
}
```

**UserPermission model**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

If I do auth()->user()->userPermission, I get all the data from the permission table for that user. Is there a way so that instead of getting the id of the permission table, I get all the permission name instead ? Maybe in an array. So user jack will have ['manage users','manage jobs']

Answer (score 0):

I saw that User and Permission have "many to many" relationships.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Make sure that the name of **User Permission table** is "permission_user", and In User model, you should define the relation method like the following :

```
public function permission() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

So when you call `auth()->user()->permission`, you can get a collection of Permission Class belong to user.

If you want to get the name of all permissions belong to an user. Just use the `pluck()` collection method.
Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: but the relationship between user and permission is inside UserPermission table

Comment: @stalwart1014  Yes, I saw that the User Permission table like a pivot table to save that relationship. What problem did you face?

Comment: I need to get all the names of the permission that user has. userPermission returns the id of the permission for that user, I need the names instead.

Comment: @stalwart1014 I got that. So I recommend you change the relation method which you declared in User model class.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use foreign and local keys in your relations.

Also take a look at Many to Many relations and pivot tables on Laravel Doc.